# Android Studio: Custom color on notification LED with ARGB does not work

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I've tried to set a custom color for the notification LED with ARGB colors.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setDefaults(0)
        .setTicker("")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.maxapplogo)
        .setContentTitle("Notification")
        .setContentText("This is a notification test!")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 500, 1000, 500, 1000 })
        .setLights(Color.GREEN, 1000, 1000)
        .build();

/* notification.ledARGB = 0xffffee05; */

/* here I wanted to know if the int values of the color can help me */
int black = Color.BLACK;
Log.d("black color", String.valueOf(black)); // -16777216

int green = Color.GREEN;
Log.d("green color", String.valueOf(green)); // -16711936

int red = Color.RED;
Log.d("red color", String.valueOf(red)); // -65536

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

if(notificationManager != null) {
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If I set the color with the command COLOR.GREEN or any other available color it will work. But with the ARGB specification it does not work. It always shows the same color even with different ARGB colors.

I've tested my app on a Samsung Galaxy S8. I don't have another smartphone to test on. Does someone has an idea why this doesn't work. It should according to other Stackoverflow posts.

Answer (score 1):

FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS and Notification.Builder.setLights(int,int,int); are deprecated since Android O ( API level 26 )

You need to use notification Channel

```
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);

mChannel.enableLights(true);
// Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
// channel, if the device supports this feature.
mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: The problem with NotificationChannel is that it doesnt work for older versions.

Comment: use this if sdk >23  for others use Notification Manager